# Scope for Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT on ViewController Initialisation

Tags: ios, swift

This is my stack trace on fabric:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread.
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000100b9ac64

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ABC 0x100b9ac64 specialized GameItemViewController.init(coder : NSCoder) -> GameItemViewController? (GameItemViewController.swift:5)
1  ABC 0x100b952f0 @objc GameItemViewController.init(coder : NSCoder) -> GameItemViewController? (GameItemViewController.swift)
2  UIKit 0x18cb6dedc -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 248
3  UIKit 0x18cccf628 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 688
4  UIKit 0x18cccf360 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 312
5  UIKit 0x18cb6db84 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 188
6  UIKit 0x18cb6e31c -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 64
7  UIKit 0x18cccf628 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 688
8  UIKit 0x18cccf7a0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1064
9  UIKit 0x18cccf360 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 312
10 UIKit 0x18cb6ced4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1164
11 UIKit 0x18ce79d88 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 196
12 UIKit 0x18ce86610 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate instantiateOrFindDestinationViewControllerWithSender:] + 92
13 UIKit 0x18ce8686c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 56
14 UIKit 0x18c99f4d0 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 108
15 ABC                     0x100b66788 GamesViewController.gameTapped(Any) -> () (GamesViewController.swift:225)
16 ABC                     0x100b66a84 @objc GamesViewController.gameTapped(Any) -> () + 4300515972
17 UIKit                          0x18c65a6c8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
18 UIKit                          0x18c77b8a4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
19 UIKit                          0x18c66077c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
20 UIKit                          0x18c7961dc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572
21 UIKit                          0x18c6dda48 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2428
22 UIKit                          0x18c6d28f8 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3160
23 UIKit                          0x18c6d1238 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
24 UIKit                          0x18ceb2c0c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2340
25 UIKit                          0x18ceb51b8 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4744
26 UIKit                          0x18ceae258 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
27 CoreFoundation                 0x1828d3404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1828d2c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1828d079c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1827f0da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
31 GraphicsServices               0x1847d3020 GSEventRunModal + 100
32 UIKit                          0x18c7d178c UIApplicationMain + 236
33 ABC                     0x100b28f60 main (GamesViewModel.swift:11)
34 libdyld.dylib                  0x182281fc0 start + 4
```

The crash occurs when i segue between GamesViewController and GameItemViewController.

I don't have any asynchronous task in my IBAction logic where i start the actual segue. I just check for 3 different booleans and start different ViewControllers respectively.

```
@IBAction func gameTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   if x {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "x", sender: nil)
    } else if y {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "y", sender: nil)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showGameItem", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

This line which the crash points to (GameItemViewController.swift:5) is the view controller declaration like so:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class GameItemViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

Also i have NOT overridden the

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?
```

OR

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

I'm not able to recreate this, however I can see logs on crashlytics with multiple devices having the issue.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434741/scope-of-causes-for-exc-breakpoint-crash - Basically what Fabric is giving you is not actually the crash, but rather an inlined Swift access error of some kind. So this report is not actually very informative. You might try exercising your app with memory sanitizer turned on or similar...

Comment: Some useful advice here too: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62269