# iOS/Swift production build crashes without error message

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I frequently get crashes in Firebase Crashlytics (tested on Sentry - the same) without any meaningful crash message. All these SIGABRT ABORT 0x, EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x, etc. I'm new to iOS and native development in general (used to Android and .NET runtimes where you get error message besides stacktrace most of the time). Do I miss smth and it's an usual stuff for iOS production builds? If so how one can debug that? Just stacktrace and line number don't answer what happened exactly. Can I expect a line number to be 100% correct at least?

Usual crash looks like this:

```
Crash: Thread #1
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001011e3d78
Crashed: Thread
0  App                            0x1011e3d78 TrackMyLocationService.determinateActivityType(withGeoCoordinate:) + 154 (TrackMyLocationService.swift:154)
1  App                            0x1011e2b70 closure #1 in TrackMyLocationService.start() (<compiler-generated>)
2  App                            0x1011c3e8c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed CLLocation, @unowned Bool) -> () (<compiler-generated>)
3  RxSwift                        0x1035415f0 closure #1 in ObservableType.subscribe(onNext:onError:onCompleted:onDisposed:) (<compiler-generated>)
4  RxSwift                        0x1035417f0 partial apply for closure #1 in ObservableType.subscribe(onNext:onError:onCompleted:onDisposed:) (<compiler-generated>)
5  RxSwift                        0x1034f7360 AnonymousObserver.onCore(_:) (<compiler-generated>)
6  RxSwift                        0x103544068 ObserverBase.on(_:) + 25 (ObserverBase.swift:25)
7  RxSwift                        0x1035441b8 protocol witness for ObserverType.on(_:) in conformance ObserverBase<A> (<compiler-generated>)
8  RxSwift                        0x103542bdc ObserveOnSink.run(_:_:) + 118 (ObserveOn.swift:118)
9  RxSwift                        0x103543e40 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned @callee_guaranteed () -> ()) -> () (<compiler-generated>)
10 RxSwift                        0x103551c4c partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed A, @unowned @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed A) -> ()) -> () (<compiler-generated>)
11 RxSwift                        0x103551238 closure #1 in RecursiveImmediateScheduler.schedule(_:) (<compiler-generated>)
12 App                            0x1010bc71c partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed ()) -> (@out Disposable) (<compiler-generated>)
13 App                            0x1010bc8a8 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out Disposable) (<compiler-generated>)
14 App                            0x1010bc71c partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed ()) -> (@out Disposable) (<compiler-generated>)
15 App                            0x1010bc8a8 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out Disposable) (<compiler-generated>)
16 App                            0x1010bc50c closure #1 in SingleBackgroundThreadScheduler.work() (<compiler-generated>)
17 App                            0x1010bc870 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Error) (<compiler-generated>)
18 libswiftObjectiveC.dylib       0x1e21f9d3c autoreleasepool<A>(invoking:) + 64
19 ???                            0x59ca81010bc424 (Missing)
20 App                            0x1010bc788 partial apply (<compiler-generated>)
21 App                            0x10127da1c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () (<compiler-generated>)
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1b357549c <redacted> + 24
23 ???                            0x27df01b3fd061c (Missing)
24 ???                            0x755881b4106c54 (Missing)
```

Comment: Can you share more details about crash and during which process your app crash?

Comment: Have you added any observer?

Comment: Yes. That is just a sample crash. The point of question is not that particular crash.The point is how much it is an usual case for iOS world to miss an error message in production crashes. For .NET it is quite unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The reason iOS sometimes has errors like this and .NET doesn't is that Swift and Objective-C are both compiled into assembly for the architecture. C# is compiled, but to a bytecode that doesn't exactly run on the hardware. Sometimes the code that Swift compiles down to doesn't have an error message associated because the error happened in the assembly itself.

Here's some more information: [Scope of causes for EXC_BREAKPOINT crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434741/scope-of-causes-for-exc-breakpoint-crash?rq=1)

Comment: .NET bytecode compiles to a native code in runtime by CLR. I don't think that bytecode gives C# unique ability to report more readable exceptions in runtime. 
At this point my line of thinking is that it's so on iOS because it's so. Like there is no big conceptual reason why Swift can't put/keep exception message in a crash log, it just doesn't do that in various cases for various reasons. Like iOS erases an error message from a crashlog produced by fatalError function due to security reasons.